# Django modal form not showing with HTMX

Tags: python, django, htmx

I have tried to replicate the example of this [Github repository](https://github.com/bblanchon/django-htmx-modal-form) but the modal form won't display using HTMX. I'm really new to HTMX and I cannot figure out why.

Here are my files:

I use a Class Based View instead of a FBV in `views.py`:

```py
class UserAddReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, RequestFormMixin, CreateView):
    """ View to create a report. """

    model = Report
    template_name = 'tool/add-report.html'
    form_class = ReportForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tool:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.request.session['report_id'] = self.object.pk
        if not self.object.slug:
            self.object.slug = slugify(str(self.object.company) + "-" + get_random_string(length=32))
        date_f = self.request.session['date_f']
        self.object.title = self.object.company.name + " " + date_f
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In `models.py`:

```py
class Report(models.Model):

    """ Class designed to create a report and assign it to a company. """

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slug)
```

In `forms.py`:

```py
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Form to create a report. """

    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['company', ]

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        user = self.request.user
        self.initial['company'] = user.company

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        filtered_date = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
        month = filtered_date.month
        month = calendar.month_name[month]
        year = filtered_date.year
        date_f = str(month) + " " + str(year)
        print(self.instance)
        self.request.session['date_f'] = date_f
```

I'm just using `company` field and a `date` field.

In `add-report.html`:

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% with WIDGET_ERROR_CLASS='is-invalid' %}
<form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken":"{{ csrf_token }}"}' class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Movie</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Company</label>
      {% render_field form.company class="form-control" placeholder="Back to the Future II" %}
      <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.company.errors|first }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="{{ form.date.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Date</label>
      {% render_field form.date class="form-control" placeholder="1980" %}
      <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.date.errors|first }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="{{ form.rating.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Rating</label >
      {% render_field form.rating class="form-control" %}
      <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.rating.errors|first }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endwith %}
```

`home.html`:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <title>My Reports</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="px-5 my-5 text-center">
        <h1>My Reports</h1>
        <p>A sample project that shows how to support modal forms with Django+HTMX with minimal JavaScript code.</p>
      </div>
      <button hx-get="{% url 'tool:add-report' %}" hx-target="#dialog" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add a report
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Placeholder for the modal -->
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
      <div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog" hx-target="this"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Empty toast to show the message -->
    <div class="toast-container position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3">
      <div id="toast" class="toast align-items-center text-white bg-success border-0" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div id="toast-body" class="toast-body"></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Scripts: Bootstraps, HTMX, and custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "assets/js/dialog.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "assets/js/toast.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do have a response `[02/Jun/2022 17:39:25] "GET /report/add-report HTTP/1.1" 200 1002`. But the modal won't display...

Answer (score 1):

Your modal is not showing becouse you not telling it to show :) in home.html you need to add to button:

```
<button 
hx-get="{% url 'tool:add-report' %}" 
hx-target="#dialog" 
class="btn btn-primary"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" <!--you need to add this line-->
    >
  Add a report
</button>
```

I'm not sure but you should change id from 'modal' to something else.

I also add this little script to modal content component to clear it after close. So in add-report.html add at the bottom:

```
<script>
    $('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $(this).html('');
        $('#modal').off('hide.bs.modal');
    });

</script>
```

To make it work move div with id 'dialog' to add-report.html, remove from this div hx-target='this' it's unnessesary here. Oh and change hx-target of button to '#modal'.